# How to add html meter element in JS variable

Tags: javascript

What is the correct way of using html element in a JavaScript variable?

I am trying to add this meter, but it doesnt work. `val_P` has a value that will be used in this meter tag.

```
output_result += "<div> P <meter value="+ val_P + " min='0' max='25'>Out of 21</meter> </div>";
```

Can you please suggest.

Comment: Are you using any libraries? And  can you show more code? It isn't very clear what you're trying to do

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information if you want help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <html>
<body>

<div><p id="data">  </p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var val_P = 10;
 var output_result = "<p> Here is the meter value </p>";
var text_P  = "<div> P <meter value='"+ val_P + "' min='0' max='25'>"+val_P+" Out of 21</meter> </div>";
 output_result += text_P;
 document.getElementById('data').innerHTML =  output_result;

</script>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you are trying to do, but from the little code you've provided I can tell you that you are concatenating val_P incorrectly.  It should be

```
output_result += "<div> P <meter value='"+ val_P + "' min='0' max='25'>Out of 21</meter> </div>";
```

You need extra ticks to arrive at a valid value property when concatenating val_P.